# ARC (automatic reference counting) active for iOS7 and disabled for iOS6 in one file

Tags: ios, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

Could a project with ARC contents a file with the flag *-fno-obj-arc*(non ARC) only for iOS 6 devices? something like a conditional flag or similar?

Comment: ARC is a compile time feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible, because ARC is a compile-time-feature, and the iOS-version can only be checked at runtime.

Furthermore, it wouldn't be actually helpful, because you would have to write the code twice, once with `-retain`s and `-release`s, and once without for ARC.